# Reference on the sum of absolute differences between $n$ samples from a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots X_n$ be $n$ samples taken of a random variable with a given distribution (so in particular it is i.i.d.). Is there literature on or a name for the random variable defined by $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left|X_i-X_{i+1}\right|?$$

If necessary feel free to add further assumptions, such as $X_i$ being non-negative, or the $X_i$ being drawn from specific distributions.

Comment: When the index represent some "time", so that $X_i$ is a discrete-time signal (or, if probability is introduced, a stochastic process) , this is known as "total variation". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising#1D_signal_series